# Can I declare ng-repeat elements inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to declare `ng-repeat` elements inside of javascript.
I googled try to find the answer but I could not find. If other ways is there please give some ideas I am really lost my way right now. 
Thank you

**HTML**

```
<div class="" ng-app='app' ng-controller='appCtrl'>
    <div ng-repeat='el in names'>
        <div ng-click="click">{{el}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
var appCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
        name: 'jane'
    }, {
        name1: 'jane1',
        name2: 'jane2'
    }, {
        name3: 'jane3'
    }];
    $scope.click = {
        // I want to declare this part 
        //
        //
        // if (el.length() == 2) {
        //     alert('true')
        // }
    }
}

app.controller('appCtrl', appCtrl())
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ek3tpmfy/4/)

Comment: The reference `el` is only available inside that ng-repeat. But why does your logic depend on ng-repeat? The ng-repeat is a view element, your logic should be independent of it.

Comment: I think you need spend time to learn JS basics, before continue work with angular.

Comment: Your second element in names has two 'name' attribute. The second one will overwrite first one.  If you want to count the length of element, please use array.

Comment: @Chang I have updated

Comment: I think he want to check whether the el contain 2 elements or not.

Comment: @prime yes absolutely true. May be I could not explained better

Comment: And the edit you have done is incorrect. then you can't access all the 'name' attributes you had before. `{{el.name}}` coz there are name,name1,name2,,,

Comment: @prime I just want to check `el` inside not `names` is it possible? I think i could not explain due to my first language is not english

Comment: @prime https://jsfiddle.net/ek3tpmfy/4/

Comment: Difficult to tell what you want to do. What are you looking to do with the 'ng-click'? Are you just looking to list all the items?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this answer](https://jsfiddle.net/prime/ek3tpmfy/6/)
I used `input` tags for the demo purpose.

```
<div class="" ng-app='app' ng-controller='appCtrl'>
<div ng-repeat='el in names'>
    <input  id="{{el.id}}" ng-click="clickz(el.id)" value = "{{el}}" > {{el}}</input>
</div>
</div>
```

The function `clickz`. If the number of `names` are equal to 2 it will alert.

```
$scope.clickz = function(id){
    //alert(id); 
    var len = document.getElementById(id).value.split(",").length-1;

    if(len == 2 ){
        alert(true)
    }

}
```